# Print top view of a Binary Tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am trying to print the top view of a binary tree. My code in python is as follows:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def top_view(root, m, hd):
    if root is None:
        return

    if hd not in m:
        m[hd] = root.data
        print hd

    top_view(root.left, m, hd-1)
    top_view(root.right,m, hd+1)

def print_top_view(root):
    m={}
    hd=0
    top_view(root, m, hd)
    for key,value in m.iteritems():
        print value,

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.right = Node(4)
root.left.right.right = Node(5)
root.left.right.right.right = Node(6)
print_top_view(root)
```

However, this gives the following output:
1 2 5 6

whereas the output should be:
1 2 3 6

Can anyone explain where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're traversing the tree in depth-first order.  I.e. you are calling top_view(root.left, m, -1), which will recursively search the entire left side of the tree.  So by the time you call top_view(root.right, m, 1), you've already set m[1] with node 5, and you don't end up putting node 3 in.

I think there are two ways you could solve this:

1) Use a queue instead of recursion - i.e. first process all nodes at level 0, then all nodes at level 1, etc.

2) Pass depth as a parameter in your recursion, and store a (node,depth) pair in your `m` dict.  Then, even if hd is in m, over-write it with a new node if it has a smaller depth than the node that is currently in m.

Answer (score 2):

in your code, lower level nodes are collecting fast than the higher level nodes,since your code is dfs.
add one more parameter(level) could solve it.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def top_view(root, m, hd,level):
    if not root:
        return 
    if hd in m:
        if level < m[hd][1]:
            m.update( {hd : [root.data,level] })
    else:
        m[hd] = [root.data,level]

    top_view(root.left, m, hd-1,level+1)
    top_view(root.right,m, hd+1, level+1)

def print_top_view(root):
    m={}
    top_view(root, m, 0,0)
    for key,value in m.iteritems():
        print value[0],

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.right = Node(4)
root.left.right.right = Node(5)
root.left.right.right.right = Node(6)
print_top_view(root)
```